# How to duplicate an audio file or trim it to a specific length in ffmpeg?

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg

I want to combine a video file (with audio) and an audio file together to get one output file.

Most importantly, I need to do the following.

If the length of the video file is longer, then you need to increase the length of the audio file to this length.

If the audio file is longer than the video file, then make the audio file shorter to match the length of the video.

**Example:**

**Video 2 minutes 5 seconds**

**Audio 1 minute -> duplicated to 2 minutes 5 seconds.**

If

**Video 1 minute**

**Audio 2 minutes 5 seconds -> trimmed to 1 minute.**

But, I can't even increase the length of the audio file.

```
export async function overlayAudio(id: number, music: Music) {
  console.log('start')
  const videoPath = path.join(__dirname, `../../../uploads/movie/${id}/result/movie/predfinal.mp4`);
  
  if (music === null) {
    return videoPath.match(/\\uploads(.*)/)[0];
  } else {
    const audioPath = path.join(__dirname, `../../../${music.audio}`);
    const outputVideoPath = path.join(__dirname, `../../../uploads/movie/${id}/result/movie/output.mp4`);
    const matchPath = outputVideoPath.match(/\\uploads(.*)/);
    const cmd = `ffmpeg -i ${videoPath} -i ${audioPath} -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=1[a];[1:a]volume=0.2[b];[b]apad[looped_audio];[a][looped_audio]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest" -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -shortest ${outputVideoPath}`;

    try {
      await execPromise(cmd);
      console.log('end!')
      return matchPath[0];
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export async function overlayAudio(id: number, music: Music) {
  console.log("start");
  
  const videoPath = path.join(
    __dirname,
    `../../../uploads/movie/${id}/result/movie/predfinal.mp4`
  );

  if (music === null) {
    return videoPath.match(/\\uploads(.*)/)[0];
  } else {
    const audioPath = path.join(__dirname, `../../../${music.audio}`);
    
    const outputVideoPath = path.join(
      __dirname,
      `../../../uploads/movie/${id}/result/movie/output.mp4`
    );

    const matchPath = outputVideoPath.match(/\\uploads(.*)/);
    const videoDurationCmd = `ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 ${videoPath}`;
    const audioDurationCmd = `ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 ${audioPath}`;

    const [videoDuration, audioDuration] = await Promise.all([
      execPromise(videoDurationCmd),
      execPromise(audioDurationCmd),
    ]);

    // Calculate the time difference
    const videoDurationValue = parseFloat(videoDuration);
    const audioDurationValue = parseFloat(audioDuration);
    const durationDifference = videoDurationValue - audioDurationValue;

    let cmd;
    if (durationDifference > 0) { // If ideo is longer than audio
      cmd = `ffmpeg -i ${videoPath} -i ${audioPath} -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=1[a];[1:a]volume=0.2[b];[b]apad[looped_audio];[a][looped_audio]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=2" -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental ${outputVideoPath}`;
    } else if (durationDifference < 0) { // If audio is longer than video
      cmd = `ffmpeg -i ${videoPath} -i ${audioPath} -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=1[a];[1:a]volume=0.2[b];[b]apad[looped_audio];[a][looped_audio]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=2" -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -t ${videoDurationValue} ${outputVideoPath}`;
    } else { // If no need to adjust
      cmd = `ffmpeg -i ${videoPath} -i ${audioPath} -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=1[a];[1:a]volume=0.2[b];[b]apad[looped_audio];[a][looped_audio]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=2" -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental ${outputVideoPath}`;
    }

    try {
      await execPromise(cmd);
      console.log("end!");
      return matchPath[0];
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the audio still plays the original amount of time, namely 1 minute, and not how long the video lasts.

And in your code, typing was complaining about

`const videoDurationValue = parseFloat(videoDuration.stdout);

const audioDurationValue = parseFloat(audioDuration.stdout);`
It was necessary to add stdout.

Comment: I tried calling ffmpeg directly from the console, but still the same. Audio is not duplicated for the entire length of the video file(((

`ffmpeg -i G:\youtube\uploads\movie\29\result\movie\predfinal.mp4 -i G:\youtube\uploads\libraryMusic\Admiring_My_Way.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=1[a];[1:a]volume=0.2[b];[b]apad[looped_audio];[a][looped_audio]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=2" -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental G:\youtube\uploads\movie\29\result\movie\output.mp4`

Comment: Solved a problem! 

ffmpeg -i G:\youtube\uploads\movie\29\result\movie\predfinal.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i G:\youtube\uploads\libraryMusic\Admiring_My_Way.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=1 [a];[1:a]volume=0.2[b];[b]apad[looped_audio];[a][looped_audio]amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=2" -c:v copy - c:a aac -strict experimental G:\youtube\uploads\movie\29\result\movie\output.mp4